# What does append(self) mean in Python classes?

Tags: python, class, object, self

I am new to OOP in Python and working on inheritance concept. I came across the following code:

```
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self, name):
        '''Return all contacts that contain the search value in their name.'''
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
        return matching_contacts

class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.all_contacts.append(self)
```

I'm wondering why do we use `self.all_contacts.append(self)` and how does `for contact in self` work ?. If I understood correctly, `self` appoints to the instance of a class (object), and appending to a list is not trivial to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically you create a list of `Contact` and appending `self` add the current contact in the `all_contacts` list.

Now for your questions,

> I'm wondering why do we use self.all_contacts.append(self)

We would use that because `all_contacts` is a  class variable which means that the list will be shared among all `Contact` instances.

> how does `for contact in self` work?

Well, as you said, since `self` represents the current instance, calling `for contact in self` is allowing you to iterate on the current Contacts list.

In other words, your code sample let you create `Contact` instance which is appended in a class variable (shared) automatically. Now, by providing a `ContactList` class that inherits from `list`, they allow you to use the implemented `search` method which will return you another list of `Contact` based on your search filter.

Answer (score 4):

`all_contacts` is a class variable -- it is unique to the class, not to each instance. It can be accessed with `Contact.all_contacts`. Whenever you create a new contact, it is appended to this list of all contacts.

`ContactList` inherits from `list`, so `for contact in self` works the same way as `for i in [1,2,3]` -- it will loop through all the items that it contains. The only thing that it does differently from a `list` is implement a new method, `search`.

Answer (score 3):

`all_contacts` is a class variable of `Contact`, initialized as an instance of `ContactList`, a subclass to `list`, so when a new `Contact` instance is instantiated via the `__init__` method, `self` is assigned with the new instance being instantiated and `self.all_contacts.append(self)` would add the new `Contact` instance to the `all_contacts` list. This way, `Contact.all_contacts` will maintain a list of all `Contact` instances that have been instantiated.